# changes in models.py not reflecting on website even after running successful makemigrations and migrate commands

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-models, vps

my models.py looks like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    PRODUCTS_CATEGORY = [
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Sterilisation', 'Sterilisation'),
        ('Cleaning Chemistry', 'Cleaning Chemistry'),
        ('Bacterial Barrier', 'Bacterial Barrier'),
        ('Waste Management', 'Waste Management'),
        ('Instrument Tracking', 'Instrument Tracking'),
        ('Validation', 'Validation')
    ]
    prod_id = models.AutoField
    prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prod_category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=PRODUCTS_CATEGORY, default='None')
    prod_desc = models.TextField()
    prod_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prod_name
```

i changed the spelling of ***Sterilisation*** to ***Sterilization*** (replacing the 's' with 'z') 
i ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and it returned 
 `Migrations for 'website': website/migrations/0003_auto_20210407_1842.py - Alter field prod_category on product` 

 i then ran `python manage.py migrate` and it returned 
`Operations to perform: Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, website Running migrations: Applying website.0003_auto_20210407_1842... OK`  
but i dont see the changes reflected on the website. the spelling still remains to be ***Sterilisation***! ***What can be the reason for this?***

 PS:  I am using sqlite3 and the website is on Ubuntu 20.04x64 which is a VPS.

Comment: Your PRODUCTS_CATEGORY isn't neccessarily held in the database so running a migration wont help -all that did was change a field name (as it told you) - did you make sure the new code made it onto the web site ?

Comment: You will need to create a data migration as well to migrate all of the existing `prod_category` values from `Sterialisation` to `Sterilization`. Changing the `choices` on a field just affects what options are displayed in a dropdown and maps from the database representation to the display representation but does nothing about data that's already been saved. Or you can be a bit more cavalier and log into a django shell in your production environment and run `Product.objects.filter(prod_category='Sterilisation').update(prod_category='Sterilization')`

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 yes, i checked the code on the website/server, its been updated!

Comment: @azundo i also have headings that display data from the model! Even the headings didn't change!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for this was given by [@azundo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11847125/azundo). 
Step 1: Get into your python django shell by using the command `python manage.py shell`
Step 2: Import the desired model where you want to make the changes by using the command `from <app_name>.models import <model_name>`  
Step 3: Use the below command
`<model_name>.objects.filter(<column_name>='<old_spelling>').update(<column_name>='<new_spelling>')`

In my case the above command was `Product.objects.filter(prod_category='Sterilisation').update(prod_category='Sterilization')`